# How to send all the Address Book contents to a server in a fast way

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, client-server, addressbook

I am writing an app where I need to send all the Address Book contents (namely the names and the numbers) to a server where crossing will be made on them to inform the user which friends from his contacts have this app installed on their device (something similar to most communication apps nowadays). My problem is not in the concept of how to do this, my problem is in the speed and synchronization between the clients and the server.

To retrieve the names and numbers from the Address Book I do a simple loop and store the answers in a `NSMutableArray` as follows:

```
for(CFIndex i=0; i< CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable); i++)
{
    record = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(peopleMutable, i);
    multi = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    //Contact ID
    contactID = (int)ABRecordGetRecordID(record);

    //Full Name
    fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty), (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];

    int multiCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
    for(CFIndex j=0; j<multiCount; j++)
    {
        number = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, j);
        [arrayNamesToSend addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u;%@;%@;", contactID, fullName, number];];
    }
}
```

Well this loop finishes in around one second (maximum 2 seconds even if you have more than 1000 contact). Lets talk about an average case: on the average one might have 500 names in the Address Book, each name is on the average 15 characters long, and each phone number is on the average 15 characters (in international format), so this leads to a total of 15,000 character to be sent to the server. Based on my modest knowledge in client server programming, it is not recommended to send large amount of bytes in one message from the client to the server, and recommended sizes are between 1024 and 4096 bytes per one message.

Now how do I send these contacts to the server? I thought of:

1. Can't send all the 15,000 characters at once in one message
2. Sending one by one (I mean contact by contact) is a very slow choice, or I can say not a realistic choice
3. Divide the whole array into chunks of 2,000 bytes (this is what I did) and send them to the server. Well theoretically this works but when I tried it I faced a problem. Sending 2,000 bytes from the iPhone to the server is very fast, but saving the received 2,000 bytes at the server in the database takes around 3 seconds, and this is causing the server to lose the subsequent contacts that were sent by the client by the time of the save.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? Is there a way to upload the whole Address Book as one file to the server and then the server will resolve it and does its work? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing, but I don't know if Apple make problems about send number of contacts to server. Have you encountered some problems? Thanks

Comment: Usually you are not allowed to use private data without the permission of the user, this is why chatting applications like whatsapp added the confirmation Alert box to access the address book. I didn't continue the project that I was working on when I asked this question therefore I don't have a solid answer for you, but most probably if you ask for user permission and he allows it then there is no problem.

Comment: Ok, but when you retrieve the number of the contacts in address book, those contacts did not give permission.. So the user give you the possibility and authorization to access to all numbers in your address book? And this is ok for Apple?

Comment: As I said I did not proceed in the project so I don't have a solid answer, but this is what chatting applications are doing. They are taking all our address book to there servers! I can not answer if Apple will approve it for your app or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a ***REALLY BAD IDEA***. You are violating all sorts of privacy concerns by sending address book data to the server. And what's more, *you don't need it*. What you should do is hash all of the data you care about (using something like SHA1, or perhaps [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) just to be safe) and send the hashes to the server. You can do your comparisons using the hashes just as well as you can using the raw data, but this way you don't have the serious privacy concerns inherent in sending actual personal data to your server.

---

In any case, your actual question is about sending a large amount of data to the server. I think your concerns are unjustified. What's wrong with sending all the data as one "message"? It sounds like you only have 15kB or so of data. That's really not that large. If you were sending even a single image to the server you'd go way over that size.

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer. I would like to comment on the idea of sending the numbers, well in fact I got this idea after reading the [privacy policy of Viber app](http://viber.com/privacypolicy.html) where they say in point 1 "A copy of the phone numbers and names in your address book will be stored on our servers..." I have a small question in case of hashing, you know such apps send APN and they write the name of your friend from your Address Book in the APN saying he joined.. Can I still do this if I hash the data? I mean getting the name on the server side?

Comment: @antf: The whole point of hashing is to ensure that the server *doesn't* have any personally identifying information. However, here's the tricky part: If your friend signs up, then he's voluntarily giving *his* name to your server, at which point you can hash it and find everyone else who has him in their address book. Now you have a real name for that person, *and* it was given voluntarily so you can go ahead and send APNs to your other users telling them that their friend has signed up.

Comment: I do agree with you but here I have something confusing me: If you install Viber you notice that the app doesn't ask you for your name, it asks for your phone number. But when another friend joins it informs you via APN with the name of your friend, and in the exact way you wrote it in your address book. So if 2 people have antf in their address book they receive it as they have it (say antf and aNTf). If Viber was using the name from the original user then all the APNs to all the user will show it in the same writing. Again I really appreciate your help and I liked your suggestions.

Comment: @antf: It sounds like Viber is scraping the address book. And as a result I will *NEVER* consider using that app. That's a horrible invasion of privacy, and other apps have gotten bad press in the past for doing exactly that. I would strongly advise not following their lead.

Comment: hahaha, I agree with you, but now you can understand why I was thinking in what you call "really bad idea" :) Simply I was looking to what others did (read their privacy that I posted up, they say that they even record your calls). I think I will go your way to produce a professional product with good standards.